# Can I roast peanuts in convection microwave?

Tags: roasting, microwave, peanuts, convection

I found a small bag of raw un-roasted peanuts, around 200 grams, in my cupboard. Any idea how can I roast these peanuts in my convection microwave oven? Would appreciate if some one can add suggestions :-)

Comment: In case you lack a microwave a standard pan or a casserole works also very well: no oil needed, just put the peanuts/almonds/pinenuts/etc. on the fire and mix often to prevent burning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [book "Madhur Jaffrey's World Vegetarian"](http://www.librarything.com/work/18021), Madhur says one of the few uses she's found for a plain microwave oven is to roast cashews. She dresses them in a little bit of oil, then spreads them out on a plate in a single layer and cooks them in the microwave oven until they turn brown. I assume dressing them in a little bit of oil helps browning. I found [a web page which has similar instructions](http://hubpages.com/hub/4-ways-to-Toast-Almonds--Cashews--Pecans--Nuts--Seeds-and-Coconut) for cashews and other nuts, but which implies the oil contained in the nuts themselves is enough to get them to brown. And finally, *about.com* has a page which is specifically about [microwave roasting peanuts](http://homecooking.about.com/cs/atozfoodindex/ht/roast_peanuts.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this also tells me to read more of cookery books than "Dive into Python" :P

Comment: Time to share my experience, make sure the peanuts are dried, don't have moisture. Sprinkling some salt may enhance the taste.

Answer (score 1):

I have roasted almonds in a convection microwave before - and they were perfect.  Just spread them out on a metal tray - and lay them out so that they are not sitting on top of each other.

Check them regularly, once they start turning brown - they're perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Take 200 grams of peanuts.  Wash them in water, remove peanuts and add little(small tea spoon) salt.  Mix with hand.  Spread the salted pea nuts in metal tray of microwave oven.  Set Convection to 4 minutes.  Switch on, on completion stir the pea nuts anf spread again then repeat the heating procedure  for another 4 minutes.  Leave the nuts inside the microwave for 10 minutes.  Take it out keep outside till it cools.(Say 30 minutes).  See the Taste and give your feed back.  Please note roasting time can be increased as per your choice.

Comment: I have been roasting nuts in microwave for last 2 months, thanks for your tip though :)